# Cucumber Step Definitions not fetching parameter value correctly

Tags: cucumber, bdd, cucumber-java, feature-file

I am trying to execute my cucumber test scenarios using `Scenario Outline` and `Examples`. As part of that, i am passing my parameters as `<parameter>` and giving the values in examples like :

```
    | val1      |
    | val2      |
```

but when i am running my tests with a basic print, then it is printing `<paramter>`, if i change the regex then it prints parameter. In simple words it is taking "parameter" as string instead of values provided in the Examples like val1, val2.

any idea why this might be happening?

PS i already tried `"<parameter>"` instead of `<parameter>` and `{string}` instead of regex

Comment: Please share the full scenario outline and examples table.

Comment: Missing header on values? Check https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/examples/calculator-java-junit5/src/test/resources/io/cucumber/examples/calculator/basic_arithmetic.feature

Comment: i was actually giving the values in the same line as "Examples :". After moving it to the next line, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake that it had put the examples data table in the same line as Examples :

```
Examples : | param1 | param2 |
           | val1   | val2   |
```

instead i had to put it like this.

```
Examples :
         | param1 | param2 |
         | val1   | val2   |
```

and now it works fine.